# Run Worksheet_Open code with a userform active

Tags: vba, excel

My program calls 7 subroutines in the workbook_open event. I want to show a progress bar (with a 'Done' button when the progress is 100%) but when I show the progress bar, it doesn't run the workbook_open event anymore until I close the userform, then it goes on running. Is there a way to show a userform with the code running in the background?

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    frmProgress.Show

    'Here it stops running the code

    frmProgress.lblTask = "Updating pivottables..."
    Call updatePivots
    ufProgress.Label1.BackColor = &H8000000D
    frmProgress.lblTask = "Updating data..."
    Call updateData
    ufProgress.Label2.BackColor = &H8000000D

    'Some More code

    frmProgress.lblTask = "Done!"
End Sub
```

I know the changing of the colors and the multiple labels are not efficient, I'm working on that.

Comment: [A reusable ProgressIndicator](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/87818/23788) might be more like what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the code in the UseForm Activate event handler which would trigger on Workbook Open event handler :)